# How to access history of all Emacs commands?

Tags: emacs, text-editors, history, command-history

I see that there is a way to access the history of the [minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229142/how-can-i-save-my-mini-buffer-history-in-emacs). I was curious if there is a way to see a history of every action in Emacs, besides just the complex ones. My purpose is to save these so I can analyze them for possible rebindings, aliases, and changing bad habits.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-History.html

Comment: that is the complex commands I mentioned in the question, for which there already exists a solution(that I linked). I am looking for all commands, not just stuff that is in the minibuffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the library **keyfreq** - https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq

It records how often you use different commands, grouped by mode. You can get a list of them with the function `keyfreq-show`:

```lisp
(defun keyfreq-show (&optional major-mode-symbol)
  "Show command usage statistics in `keyfreq-buffer'.
If MAJOR-MODE-SYMBOL is given, the function shows the statistics
for that particular major mode only.
With a universal argument, the major-mode of the current buffer
is used as MAJOR-MODE-SYMBOL argument."
```

or `keyfreq-html`

```lisp
(defun keyfreq-html (filename &optional confirm)
  "Save an HTML file as FILENAME with all the statistics of each mode."
```

or `keyfreq-json`.

Xah Lee has a good writeup, with some results from using an older version of it for 4+ million command calls - http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/command-frequency.html